# Apply bindings and subscribe on change of discount amount totals.totals() in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, knockoutjs, coupon-codes

in my checkout page when `promo code` is applied, I am updating a text using some calculation using knockoutjs

In my checkout page, on applying and removing `promo code`, it changes the `discount` key in `totals.totals().items`.
How to apply `bindings` and `subscribe` in knockoutjs,
so that I can call my function which I am calling from my HTML.

> Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
 <span class="tag-text">
    <!-- ko if: getFinalSale($parent)-->
      <u class="product-tag underline-bold-text checkout-final-sale" data-bind="text: getFinalSale($parent)"></u>
    <!-- /ko -->
</span>
```

I have written above code in details.html

and my js is

> Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js

knockout js

```
  define([
   'uiComponent',
   'ko',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
    ], function (Component, ko, totals) {
   'use strict';
    var finalSaleData = window.checkoutConfig.items;

    return Component.extend({
     defaults: {
         template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
     },
    quoteItemData: quoteItemData,
    finalSaleData: finalSaleData,

    /**
     * @param {Object} quoteItem
     * @return {String}
     */

    getItems: function(item_id) {
        var itemElement = null;
        _.each(this.finalSaleData, function(element, index) {
            if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                itemElement = element;
            }
        });
        return itemElement;
    },
    getFinalSale : function (quoteItem) {
        var item = this.getItems(quoteItem.item_id);
        var temp_item = this.getTempItems(quoteItem.item_id);
        var tagText = '';

        if((((temp_item.price*temp_item.qty) - temp_item.discount_amount)/(item.base_old_price*temp_item.qty)) < 0.5){
            var tagText = 'Final Sale';
        }else{
            if(item.base_old_price && temp_item.price){
                // && item.price < item.price && item.base_old_price / item.price <= 0.5){
                if(((item.base_old_price - temp_item.price)/item.base_old_price)>0.5){
                    var tagText = 'Final Sale';
                }
            }
        }
        return tagText;
    }, 
  });
});
```

I am using `var finalSaleData = window.checkoutConfig.items` in my function `getFinalSale`.

How to make `getFinalSale` function run every time when `window.checkoutConfig.items` data is changed without refreshing the page.

1) How can i call getFinalSale on the change of `totals.totals().items`

2) The issue I am passing the `$parent` from my HTML and when the `totals.totals().items` the discount amount is changed for each item after applying `promo code` then how will I pass this `$parent`(quoteItem) from the very same js.

How to solve that.

The problem is, this runs only when the page reloads.

How to make `getFinalSale` function run every time the user applies `promo code` without refreshing the page so that my HTML gets updated too.

Basically `Final Sale` text needs to be shown on the basis of that logic in js code in `getFinalSale` function.

And also, `data-bind="text: getFinalSale($parent)` i am calling this from HTML and I am using subscribe also but then how i will pass `$parent` parameter from subscribing so that `getFinalSale` runs when `this.totals` changes everytime after applying coupon.

```
initialize: function(){
        this._super();
        this.totals.subscribe(function (data) {
          this.getFinalSale(data)
        }, this);
    } ,
```

The `data` parameter is not same as `$parent` which i passed it from html.
and it breaks the js.

Comment: Did you override this js?

Comment: yes vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js this was the vender file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was simple,
To make `getFinalSale`  function run every time data of `price`/`discount` changes

Use `totals: quote.getTotals()`

```
   return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
    },
    quoteItemData: quoteItemData,
    finalSaleData: finalSaleData,
    saleData: saleData,
    totals: quote.getTotals(),
    /**
     * @param {Object} quoteItem
     * @return {String}
     */


    getFinalSale : function (quoteItem) {
        var tagText = '';
        var price = 0;
        if(this.totals()) {
                var item = null;
                _.each(this.finalSaleData , function(element, index) {
                    if (element.item_id == quoteItem.item_id) {
                        item = element;
                    }
                });

                var temp_item = null;
                _.each(this.totals().items, function(element, index) {
                    if (element.item_id == quoteItem.item_id) {
                        temp_item = element;
                    }
                });

                var discount = this.getDiscountPureValue(quoteItem.item_id);

                if ((((temp_item.price * temp_item.qty) - discount) / (item.base_old_price * temp_item.qty)) < 0.5) {
                    price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value;
                } else {
                    if (item.base_old_price && temp_item.price) {
                        if (((item.base_old_price - temp_item.price) / item.base_old_price) > 0.5) {
                            price = totals.getSegment('grand_total').value
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        return price;
    },
});
```

and also to get the updated discount value always

Use `this.totals()` instead of `this.totals` which was the mistake, I was doing.

```
 getDiscountPureValue: function (id) {
        var price = 0;
        var item = null;
        if (this.totals() && this.totals().items){
            _.each(this.totals().items , function(element, index) {
                if (element.item_id == id) {
                    item = element;
                }
            });
            price = item.discount_amount;
        }

        return price;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url. Its demo for windows.checkoutConfig.items

https://www.webnexs.com/blog/kb/include-variable-window-checkout-config-magento-checkout/

https://webkul.com/blog/update-cart-totals-by-js-on-checkout-page-magento2/

I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: have you checked in inspect element, when you update data than details.js execute every-time/

Comment: when I apply or remove coupon , totals.totals() still gives me old value and i get discount 0 when i apply for coupon, that means my function getFinalSale runs before the apply coupon thats why it gets the old values from totals.totals() and my logic doesnt work, and when i inspect `totals.totals()` after the apply coupon has finished, it then shows the latest discounted values

Comment: Updated the question as well

Comment: apply with this lines 
cartCache.set('totals',null);
defaultTotal.estimateTotals();

Comment: where should i add these lines

Comment: inside getFinalSale, first check with console.log for price are getting or not.

Comment: How will I solve the totals.totals()  latest value issue. getFinalSale runs before the coupon applied, somehow if we run getFinalSale only if the totals.totals()  object is changed/ or after the apply coupon ajax is finished then problem would be solved

Comment: cartCache.set('totals',null); defaultTotal.estimateTotals();  - add this line inside getFinalSale function.

Comment: did, so i dont need to any observables or subscribe ?